# Pass tuple to function that takes *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, argument-unpacking

I have two functions:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def foo2():
    return list(), dict()
```

I want to be able to pass the list and dict from foo2 as args and kwargs in foo, however when I use it like

```
foo(foo2())
```

or

```
foo(*foo2())
```

tuple returned by foo2 gets assigned to *args.
How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to *unpack* your `foo2()` arguments into two names *first*, you can't directly use the two return values as `*args` and `**kwargs` with existing syntax.

Use:

```
args, kwargs = foo2()
foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I thought about that but I hoped there would be a better way to do it. Thanks a lot!